# usercontrol open different windows c#

Tags: c#, wpf

hello i am having some problem while using user control in wpf. i have single image in user control . i want to place this user control on my main window which contains some map.i am placing this user control(image) on my main window.they are 10 t0 15 .what i want is to open different windows by clicking on this usercontrol which is just an image . but when i do that it show me only same window every time . is there any way so i just have to create single user control and use it multiple times to open different windows .like (window1,window2,window3) etc..

kindly help me . i will be really thankfull.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="Demo.WindowsPresentation.CustomMarkers.CustomMarkerDemo"
Height="40" Width="30" Opacity="10">
    <Image MouseDown="clickit" Name="icon" Source="bigMarkerGreen.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

**In cs**

```
this.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(clickit);
     void clickit(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("test");
            main.show();
        }
```

Comment: Place some of your relevant code in the question

Comment: i edited my question .thats the user control

Comment: Please also include the parts where you are opening the window currently by clicking on this user control.

Comment: look here its opening main ...but how can i open different windows by placing single user control ..

Comment: What is the criteria of opening these different windows? I believe you only want to open a different image in the window based on which image was clicked, isn't?

Comment: i have to show pushpins on map thats why i am using usercontrol .. now when user click different pushpins it should open different windows .. although its single user control but i want to know if its possible

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand by the given information, you want to open this UserControl in different windows. I would suggest you to create a window and add this UserControl onto it like

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.WindowsPresentation.CustomMarkers.win.winCustomMarker"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:marker="clr-namespace:Demo.WindowsPresentation.CustomMarkers"
        Title="Window" Height="345" Width="380">
    <Grid>
        <marker:CustomMarkerDemo></marker:CustomMarkerDemo>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then in your mouse click event:

```
void clickit(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    winCustomMarker customMarkerWindow = new winCustomMarker();
    //bind any information you want that you want to pass to your inner UserControl
    customMarkerWindow.show();
}
```

Comment: you did not get my point .. it will always open same window no matter how many times i use this .. i want to open different windows by using single user control

Comment: Use Ali's way, but check which pushpin that the user clicked on and decide which window to open. Just use the same `clickit` method above, and add a few `if()` statements to decide which window to open.

Comment: @dubstylee I honestly didn't get the purpose of creating so many windows for just displaying an image. We can pass the clicked information to our 1 window and process it according to the needs!

Comment: @AliBaig I agree, but OP wanted to have separate windows, so I was just suggested how he could accomplish that :)

Comment: its not like that i am creating so many windows to display an image ..this image will work like button . i want to place this image which is usercontrol on main window which have map .. so whenever this user control is clicked i want to show windows .. for example if have placed 5 on different location it should show me 5 different windows... 

there is just a single user control .

Answer (score 0):

You may consider launching them as separate processes. Move user control to a new WPF project(.exe) and from main app create as many instances of user control you need.

```
        var imgUserControlProcess = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ImageUserControl.exe",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        };

        var processStart = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = mainViewProcess
        };
        processStart.Start();
```